# Jgit - Get All commits from branch

Tags: java, automation, jgit

Good day
Guys i have some problem with Jgit
I try to get all commits from branch - but Jgit skip half of commits

Commit: Tue Nov 26 15:26:19 EET 2019
Commit: Tue Nov 26 14:28:01 EET 2019
Commit: Wed Nov 13 15:44:40 EET 2019
Commit: Tue Nov 12 16:27:27 EET 2019

i have a big scope of commits between 26 of November to 13

Here is my code

```
 RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo);
 walk.markStart(walk.parseCommit(repo.resolve(Constants.HEAD)));
 walk.sort(RevSort.TOPO);// chronological order
 walk.setRevFilter(RevFilter.ALL);

 for(RevCommit commit : walk ) {
  System.out.println(commit.getAuthorIdent().getWhen());
}
```

if we check gitLab - the last commit before skip was  Nov 26
in that commit developer merge 'current branch' into 'Some test branch'

After that commit we have a big skip 
I hope that some of you already had this problem and may help me )

Answer (score 1):

See this [snippet](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/WalkAllCommits.java) in the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook), basically you can use the "Log" command to achieve this:

```
        try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
            ObjectId branchId = repository.resolve("somebranch");
            Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().add(branchId).call();
            int count = 0;
            for (RevCommit commit : commits) {
                System.out.println("LogCommit: " + commit);
                count++;
            }
        }
```